# Push An ArrayList of Strings Into HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to split each element of an ArrayList into a char and double and push the results into a HashMap. So far, my code is this:

```
public static int TotalAmount(ArrayList<String> x) {
    HashMap<Character,Double> hm = new HashMap<Character,Double>();
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        String[] s = x.get(i).split("(?<=\\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])");
        hm.put(s[1].charAt(0), Double.parseDouble(s[0]));;
    }
```

I do this with the ArrayList holding:

```
234K
1.3M
2.1M
211H
11K
```

But when I iterate through the HashMap, I get:

```
H, 211
K, 11
M, 2.1
```

I cannot seem to find where my logic went wrong. I might be able to accredit this to my intro to HashMaps. How do I ensure that I convert the ArrayList of Strings into a HashMap correctly?

To clear things up, I'm trying to completely move the ArrayList into a HashMap, without overwriting when the same key is found.

Comment: What were you expecting to get?  What do you mean by "convert the ArrayList of Strings into a HashMap correctly"?  What is "correctly"?

Comment: So if you add `'M'` 1.3 and again `'M'` 2.1, won't the second one override the 1st entry in Map?

Comment: `put` *overrides* any value already associated with the same key. You need to declare your map as `HashMap<Character,List<Double>>` and `add` your values to that list instead.

Comment: Dang, how did I forget that?! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    public static HashMap<Character, List<Double>> TotalAmount(ArrayList<String> initialList) {

        HashMap<Character, List<Double>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (String line : initialList) {
            Double size = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(0, line.length() - 1));
            Character sizeChar = line.charAt(line.length() - 1);

            if (resultMap.containsKey(sizeChar)) {
                resultMap.get(sizeChar).add(size);
            } else {
                resultMap.put(sizeChar, Collections.singletonList(size));
            }
        }

        return resultMap;
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively, rather than maintaining `List<Double>` you can use Multimap from Apache Commons-  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html.

Comment: The reason I'm returning an int is that the exercise I'm doing requires that I return a total of all the doubles from the hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! I tested and it works fine! As QBrute mentioned, HashMap's **put()** overrides any value that is processed with the same key earlier.

I created method and the test(in main) using  HashMap>
.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("234K");
        list.add("1.3M");
        list.add("2.1M");
        list.add("221H");
        list.add("11K");

    HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Double>> result = TotalAmount(list);
    System.out.println("K: " + result.get('K'));
    System.out.println("M: " + result.get('M'));
    System.out.println("H: " + result.get('H'));
}

public static HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Double>> TotalAmount(
        ArrayList<String> x) {

    HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Double>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String line : x) {
        Double num = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(0,
                line.length() - 1));
        Character c = line.charAt(line.length() - 1);

        if (map.containsKey(c)) {
            map.get(c).add(num);
        } else {
            ArrayList<Double> newList = new ArrayList<>();
            newList.add(num);
            map.put(c, newList);
        }
    }

    return map;
}
}
```